# delayed_job gives "NameError: uninitialized constant"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, nameerror

I'm trying to move a current working task (in production and in the console) to use delayed_job in a Rails 2 app but keep getting the error:

```
ThermalImageJob failed with NameError: uninitialized constant Barby::Code128B
```

I've pored through others' code searching for an answer to no avail.  Here's my code:

/lib/thermal_image_job.rb

```
class ThermalImageJob < Struct.new(:order_id)
  def perform
    order = Order.find(order_id)
    order.tickets.each do |ticket|
      ticket.barcodes.each do |barcode|
        barcode.generate_thermal_image
      end
    end
  end
end
```

/app/controllers/orders_controller.rb

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(ThermalImageJob.new(@order.id))
```

/app/models/barcode.rb

```
def generate_thermal_image(format=:gif)
  filename = "#{barcode}_thermal.#{format}"
  temp_file_path = File.join("#{RAILS_ROOT}", 'tmp', filename)
  unless FileTest.exists?(temp_file_path)
    barcode_file = File.new(temp_file_path, 'w')
    code = Barby::Code128B.new(barcode)
      ....
end
```

Gemfile

```
gem "delayed_job", "2.0.7"
gem "daemons", "1.0.10"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after much head banging, I figured it out, so I'm posting this to help the next person.  The problem was that it couldn't find the barby libs, so I added a require at the beginning of my class:

```
require "barby/outputter/rmagick_outputter"
require "barby/barcode/code_128"
```

Comment: This was actually in the post-install message from barby - `Barby no longer require all barcode symbologies by default. You'll have
to require the ones you need. For example, if you need EAN-13,
require 'barby/barcode/ean_13'; For a full list of symbologies and their filenames, see README.`